# HTML Agility Pack - Removing hyperlinks parent to an image

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

To make the code simple to explain, I have the following code in which I am taking HTML and using HAP to find all image `src` and replacing it with a number.

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(htmlString);                
int Counter = 0;
document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
         .Where(e =>
          {
           string src = e.GetAttributeValue("src", null) ?? "";
           return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src);
          })
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(x =>
            {
            string currentSrcValue = x.GetAttributeValue("src", null);                                
            localImgPath = "<Somepath>IMG_" + Counter.ToString() + ".jpg";                      
            Counter++;
            });
           x.SetAttributeValue("src", localImgPath);
          });
```

**INPUT** : `<img src="https://imagepath"/>`

**OUTPUT**: `<img src="<somepath>IMG_1.jpg"/>`

Now this works perfectly

but the issue I am facing is, some of the images are inside the `hyperlink` such as

```
<a href="https://imagepath"><img src="https://imagepath"/></a>
```

While processing images I want to find out if the image is inside the hyperlink and remove the hyperlink such as the following

**INPUT** : `<a href="https://imagepath"><img src="https://imagepath"/></a>`

**OUTPUT**: `<img src="<somepath>IMG_1.jpg"/>`

A point to be noted that I do not want to remove all hyperlinks in my HTML, only hyperlink which is a parent of an image.

Is it possible using HAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the below code. You would want to grab all the image elements and check the parent. If the parent is a link you should add it to a list of Nodes that you want removed.

```
var images = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").ToList();

var nodesToRemove = new List<HtmlNode>();

foreach (var image in images)
{
    var parent = image.ParentNode;
    if (parent.Name.Equals("a"))
    {
        nodesToRemove.Add(parent);
    }
}
```

Then remove those nodes by getting its parent and calling the `RemoveChild` method. This will take the node you want removed, plus a bool stating whether or not to keep the grandchildren (which in this case you would want to since you want to keep the image elements).

```
foreach (var node in nodesToRemove)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
}
```